# Responsive page with javaScript

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, responsive

I have a container which I want to hide when screen is less than 1000px.

**css**

`.desktop-links { display: none; }`

`.active { display: block; }`

`.in-active { display: none; }`

**JavaScript**:

```
const desktopLinks = document.querySelector('.desktop-links');

shareBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(window.innerWidth < 1000) {
        
        phoneLinks.classList.toggle('active');
        profile.classList.toggle('in-active');
    } else {
        desktopLinks.classList.toggle('active');
    }
});
```

**bug**:

When page is load in desktop, if I click on `shareBtn` and window screen is more than 1000px, `desktopLinks` shows as I intend, but if I resize browser screen while `desktopLinks.style.display = "block"`, then I can see it in mobile size or if when the page is loading screen size is on moblie size, and if I resize it to fullscreen, and I should reload the page in order to functionality work as I want, how can I fix this bug?

**what I did**

I tried to use while and for loops to fix the bug but I ended up crash the page and add `desktopLinks.style.display = 'none'` in if statement but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please use CSS media queries for this, not javascript. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: You mean, there's a button, that when clicked will show a different element depending on screen width, right?

Comment: there is a button that if the screen size is small, don't show at all, but on bigger screen after clicking on it, it will show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JS, create a window `resize` event to check if it should swap your menu type:

JS:

```js
const desktopLinks = document.querySelector('.desktop-links');

shareBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 1000) {
    phoneLinks.classList.toggle('active');
    profile.classList.toggle('in-active');
  } 
  else {
    desktopLinks.classList.toggle('active');
  }
});

window.addEventListener('resize', e => {
  if(window.innerWidth <= 1000 && desktopLinks.classList.contains('active')) {
    desktop.classList.toggle('active')
    phoneLinks.classList.toggle('active');
    profile.classList.toggle('in-active');
  } 
  else if (window.innerWidth > 1000 && phoneLinks.classList.contains('active')) {      
    desktop.classList.toggle('active')
    phoneLinks.classList.toggle('active');
    profile.classList.toggle('in-active');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately, I cant upvote at this time because of my reputation.

Comment: no problem, helping someone already makes me feel something cool

Answer (score 2):

You can try tu handle resize Event instead of click:

```
 window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        if(window.innerWidth < 1000) {
            
            phoneLinks.classList.toggle('active');
            profile.classList.toggle('in-active');
        } else {
            desktopLinks.classList.toggle('active');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately, I can't upvote at this time because of my reputation. yes I add resize and  it worked as I wanted.